# Result of return data array is empty but console log returning data

Tags: javascript, arrays, adonis.js

I have some problem when i'm try to return json array using `return array_name`, but when i'm try to console.log that array result is data that i want to see. I don't know what's wrong with my code..

this is example for data json array:

```
[ {
    id_item : 1,
    qty : 2
  },
  {
    id_item : 2,
    qty : 5
  }
]
```

then, this is my code:

```
            const id = []; /*to get array id_item from example data above*/
            for (var i = 0; i < detail.length; i++) {
                id[i] = detail[i].id_item;
            }
            const stock = await DB
                        .from('items')
                        .where('id_company',users.id_company)
                        .whereIn('id_item', id); /* try to get data that match with params id */

            const dt = [];
            for (var x = 0; x < stock.length; x++) {
                dt[stok[x].id_item] = stock[x].stock;
                dt[stok[x].item_name] = stock[x].item_name;
            }

            return dt;   /* the result is just [] */
            console.log(dt);   /* the result is = [ '1': 2, Hat: 'hat','2': 5, Sneakers : 'sneakers'] */
```

Comment: Can you show the consumer of this function? Sounds like it's not waiting for the Promise

Comment: this is just using ```async functionName({ request, response })``` like that

Comment: No, where is the *consumer* of whatever function this is in?

Comment: The piece of code you are showing looks fine. Given that you said your code is in an `async` function, you are likely mistakenly using the `Promise` that the function returns instead of the value you want. But I cannot be sure without seeing that part of the code. `consumer` just means the function that is calling this function you are showing.

Comment: i guess what's you mean in variable ```dt```?

Comment: const dt = {}; // looks like you want to fill Object into Array ?? If it would be Array, then there is push method.